# Previous page button use results in multiple current page button states

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where if the previous page browser button is used, the current page button state for the page that was previously viewed remains. This results in that multiple menu items appear in their 'current' state when the previous page browser button is used. If the 'current' state of the previously viewed page is rolled over, it reverts to it's normal state. Doesn't make sense? [Click here to view the site.](http://www.goldencreekolives.com.au/dev/) I've never had this issue before, and tired everything! Any advice appreciated!

Comment: I'm not getting that issue...

Comment: It doesn't have the issue on IE8 for PC, however the issue occurs with Firefox on PC, Firefox and Safari on Mac, and on Mobile and Ipad viewing.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows. You may want to post any associated Javascript that assigns the current class. If not, it is probably just caching issues.

Comment: I don't use any javascript to assign the current class, just place in an image with alternate states and links removed. Modifying the function MM script in the head doesn't influence it. Never had this issue before.... weird.

Comment: In IE, just try clearing your cache and refreshing the page. See if that changes anything.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also not experiencing this in IE9 on Windows.

Comment: Tried that in all programs. IE8 for PC is all good. Problem just occurs with all other browsers.

Comment: tried this `<body onload="MM_swapImgRestore();Everything_Else();">` ? a bit hackish, i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that when you leave the page and then go back, your original image (which was hovered when you left) isn't getting swapped back to its non-hover state until the `mouseout` event occurs.

My suggestion would be to use `background-image` instead of `img`s, and then you can change it on hover easily using the CSS `:hover` selector, something like:

```
<a id = "groove" href = "/groove/">

</a>
```

CSS:

```
#groove {
    background-image: url('groove.gif');
    height: 20px; /*just an example*/
    width: 100px; /*another example*/
}
#groove:hover {
    background-image: url('groovehover.gif');
}
```

I hope that helped!

Comment: Definitely not experiencing the issue in Chrome.

Comment: @Purmou Yep, apparently Chrome is smarter with `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've used this option before, but I really didn't think I'd need to for this.

Comment: @Abody97 I appear to be having a bit of trouble implementing your suggested solution. I've placed the CSS and set up a couple of test buttons on [this page](http://www.goldencreekolives.com.au/dev/) but they are hot showing up. 'Grove' and 'Current Activities' should be sitting next to home. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidKneale The URLSs to the `background-image`s is wrong, apparently. Since they're relative to your CSS file, use the full URL, instead -- something like: `http://www.goldencreekolives.com.au/dev/images/groove.gif` (just an example, don't know the real one).

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as there is no Javascript associated with this, it seems like a simple issue of caching.

In any affected browser, try clearing your cache and then refreshing the page.

Comment: Line 79 in his `/dev/`s HTML: `<a href="grove.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('grove','','images/grove_over.gif',1)">` -- looks like JavaScript to me.